# The type initializer for 'WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Internal.NDoc' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, initialization, abcpdf

I have installed a software ABCPDF7, which converts a html file to pdf and saves it.

I am facing an error:

```
 ERROR MESSAGE :The type initializer for 'WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Internal.NDoc' threw an exception. ERROR DETAILS : at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Internal.NDoc.New() at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc..ctor()
```

on line :

```
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc oDoc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc();
```

======

This error is coming in one old application.

So for cross checking I did create a dummy app, and executed the code in same box and everything worked fine.

Any idea where is it failing in existing app?

Answer (score 1):

ABCpdf7 requires two DLLs to be accessible: ABCPDF.DLL and ABCPDFCE7.DLL. Both must be the same version (down to the minor release number) and also must both match the bitness of the machine they are running on (32-bit or 64-bit).

Perhaps one of the DLLs in the old application is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue after Deployment , The issue could be **Application Pool** . It need to be configured to enable **32 bit Application** . Please see attached (Embedded) Screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkZpA.png